# Cmd (and keyboard) does not work when typing a password

Tags: ssh, cmd

Like title & image: I am trying to enter password but it does not work, nothing shows up.

I tried paste password with <kbd>Ctrl + V</kbd>. It does not work either.

Any solution?

[cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkj8v.png)

Comment: Well some password command line programs don't show input when entering a password. I know GitHub moved away from passwords, but this used to be the case there...I'm sure it is standard. Are you sure your password is not just wrong?

Comment: yes as you said
Thank you very much <3

Comment: If this question will not help anyone in the future, please delete it. Thanks.

Comment: @lit the question is ceirtainly wrong. but it's a mistake many others will make. I guess the password better be here so it doesn't get asked again. If it has been already been asked many times, you can flag it as repeated, and futher doings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ViaTech say, sometimes passwords doesn't show when you're typing them, but it doesn't mean they're not being read. Simply type and enter your password.

If process is stuck, try `ctrl + c`

Also, for inserting stuff into cmd, you can try with `shift + ctrl + v`, or `insert + v` if that's the problem.

Comment: yes, it stoped, but I want to enter password not stop :(